# How to rotate image about its centre rather than about the canvas it is on in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm still learning how to make apps in WPF, and im struggling a little.

Im trying to rotate individual rectangles about its centre, but they are being rotated about the canvas that it is placed on. I read about RenderTransformOrigin, and I set it to 0.5,0.5 but its still rotating relative to the canvas.

```
<ItemsControl Name="canvasDataBinding"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="256" 
        Margin="294,35,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="256"
        ClipToBounds="False">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Background="#FFBBBBBB">
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>

                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Height="{Binding Height}" 
                           Width="{Binding Width}"
                           Stroke="Black" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Name}">
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is what it is currently doing:
[image]

**Edit:**
Here it is when I apply the rotation with ImageBrush.RelativeTransform
[image]

I tried setting ClipToBounds = "False" on the rectangle but im getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set  RelativeTransform to on the image rather than the rectangle,

```
  <Image ImageSource="{Binding Name}">
  <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
       <TransformGroup>
         <TranslateTransform X="{Binding OffsetX}" Y="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
              <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
        </TransformGroup>
   </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
   </ImageBrush>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its rotating how I want it but now the image is being clipped by the rectangle. I edited my post with an image.

Comment: you dont wnat the rectangle?

Comment: No. I just need the image. I was under the impression that I need to put the image inside something. Can I just populate my canvas with multiple images? I only began working with wpf so im fairly clueless.

Comment: @Infodayne Yes you dont need a rectangle here, just use the image and use rendertransform inside the image

Comment: Got rid of the rectangle. Now I just have an Image, and im using RenderTransform. However I cant use RelativeTransform because its not an ImageBrush, so its rotating about the canvas again.

Comment: Without render just apply Rotate transform and it should work,did you try to remove the stroke of rectangle, then you wont be seeeing the border

Comment: How do you do this in code?